# Can we globaly on or off XSS filter in kohana v 3.0?

Tags: kohana-auth

Can we globally set `on` or `off` XSS filter in Kohana v 3.0?

I have the following search

```
 $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

it should globally activate `xss` by checking, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'global_xss_filtering' option applies to Kohana v2.
I suggest you read the [xss security security guide for Kohana 3.0](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/security/xss).